# Using regular expressions in Fitnesse to test currency values

Tags: regex, unit-testing, fitnesse

Very new to Fitnesse, I need to write a test using regular expressions to test floating point precision...

```
$24.59   TEST: starts with '$' and precision is 2 decimal places
```

I tried this but it did not work, thinking it's a syntax problem, I just need to get the regex expression correct, I don't need the full test fixture

```
/^$\d+.\d{2}$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the [match-characters](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node79.html) if you want match it on string. In this case, `$` and `.`.

```
/^\$\d+\.\d{2}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first dollar sign needs to be escaped.

```
/^\$\d+\.\d{2}$/
```

And as another pointed out, the dot should be escaped too, otherwise it will match *any* character.